# GCP Access Context Manager with IP range

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ipv6, vpc, google-vpc

I have a problem/question regarding GCP's Access Context Manager. I am just trying it out together with VPC Service Control and my idea is to limit access to GCP services within specific project.

What I did was I created service perimeter, added `storage.googleapis.com` as restricted service and attached access level to it.
Within access level I set up a condition to allow my public IPv4 CIDR (x.x.x.x/32). With that condition, I keep getting `ERROR: Could not fetch resource: - Request is prohibited by organization's policy`.
What I figured is if I add my public IPv6 CIDR in the condition, this works.

Any idea why this would not work on IPv4 address (I even added 0.0.0.0/0 for test there, but the error still persisted)? When going through logs, I see that within the `requestMetadata.callerIp`, IPv6 is used.
I was trying to use both `gcloud` CLI as well as GCP console for testing access.

Best regards,
Bostjan

Answer (score 0):

refer the link about how system chooses IPv6 or IPv4 protocol
[how do client applications know to use IPv4 or IPv6](https://superuser.com/questions/403716/how-do-client-applications-know-to-use-ipv4-or-ipv6#:%7E:text=There%20the%20operating%20system%20actually,might%20switch%20back%20to%20IPv6.)

If you disable IPv6 in your system then resources will be accessed through IPv4 address.Then the access level specified with IPv4 works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).